# Slack slash command - Accept media files (image, video, voice memo)

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I've built a slash command on slack that tries to utilize slack's built-in file upload and accepts text together with media files (and posts it to another channel if specific keywords are present).

However, whenever I get the payload of the command I only get the textual part of the message, and the image/video/voice memo are left out.

Is it possible to get user uploaded files through a slash command or slack bot?
How shall I go about it?

I've tried adding the scopes `files:read` and `files:write` (together with the standard `commands`) and sent a message with an uploaded image or voice memo (recorded via slack).

In both cases all I got was only the text part of the command:

```
token=<TOKEN>&team_id=<TEAM_ID>&team_domain=<DOMAIN>&channel_id=<CHANNEL_ID>&channel_name=directmessage&user_id=<USER_ID>&
user_name=<USERNAME>&command=%2Fcreate&text=can+I+send+a+%23voice+%23memo&
api_app_id=<APP_ID>&is_enterprise_install=false&
response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2F<...>&trigger_id=<TRIGGER_ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [Slack Bolt](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started) library which supports all the new slack features and events.
By doing that you gain access to the full message `body`, which also includes the `event` attribute, in which you can find `files` array.

Code sample:

```
const { App } = require('@slack/bolt');

const app = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
  socketMode: true,
  appToken: process.env.SLACK_APP_TOKEN
});

// Listens to incoming messages that contain "hello"
app.message('hello', async ({ message, say, logger, body, event }) => {
    // notice event.files
    logger.info('Body', body, 'Files', event.files);

    await say(`Hey there <@${message.user}>!`);
});
```

This message will react to any message containing "hello", log `files` array within `event` and reply with a friendly message.

Example `files` array logged by the logger (3 seconds voice memo in this case):

```
[
  {
    id: '<file-id>',
    created: 1671452738,
    timestamp: 1671452738,
    name: 'audio_message.webm',
    title: 'audio_message.webm',
    mimetype: 'audio/webm',
    filetype: 'webm',
    pretty_type: 'WebM',
    user: '<user-id>',
    user_team: '<team-id>',
    editable: false,
    size: 39033,
    mode: 'hosted',
    is_external: false,
    external_type: '',
    is_public: false,
    public_url_shared: false,
    display_as_bot: false,
    username: '',
    subtype: 'slack_audio',
    transcription: { status: 'processing' },
    url_private: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/<ids>/audio_message_audio.mp4',
    url_private_download: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/<ids>/download/audio_message_audio.mp4',
    duration_ms: 2421,
    aac: 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/<ids>/audio_message_audio.mp4',
    audio_wave_samples: [
       1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
       0,  0,  0, 12, 37, 47, 54, 62, 68,  79, 80, 58,
      39, 30, 22, 18, 46, 82, 87, 90, 94, 100, 96, 72,
      51, 76, 77, 62, 38, 47, 51, 51, 60,  68, 70, 60,
      52, 42, 54, 66, 62, 61, 63, 50, 53,  55, 58, 47,
      40, 36, 32, 27, 23, 16, 11,  6,  4,   4,  4,  3,
       2,  2,  4,  5,  4,  3,  3,  3,  2,   2,  2,  2,
       1,  1,  1,  1
    ],
    media_display_type: 'audio',
    permalink: 'https://<workplace-id>.slack.com/files/<file-id>/audio_message.webm',
    permalink_public: 'https://slack-files.com/<file-id>',
    has_rich_preview: false,
    file_access: 'visible'
  }
]
```

I couldn't find any specific documentation about sending files to a slack bot, hopefully that helps.